# get object from json string in iOS - Xcode

Tags: ios

i have "JSON" String like this.

**

> {"success":true,"domains":[{"URL":"","name":"Test
>   Alpha","id":"100"}]}

**

i want to check is success is true and, if it is true, get the URL.

how can i do this in  **iPhone application** - **xcode**?

Comment: Convert to NSDictionary and check the value for key.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData* data = [myStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
if(YES == dictionary[@"success"])
{
    NSString *urlString = dictionary[@"domains"][0][@"URL"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be hep you.

For example your response is NSData like below :

```
NSData *data =  [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                          returningResponse:nil
                                                      error:&error];
NSMutableDictionary *_dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
NSString *Success = [_dict valueForKey:@"success"];
```

You will get your desire output in `Success`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSJSONSerialization` to get an `NSMutableDictionary`, check if `success` is true (`YES`), and if so, get the URL. E.g., the following should result in URL: www.mydomain.com being output to the debug window:

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"success\":true,\"domains\":[{\"URL\":\"www.mydomain.com\",\"name\":\"Test Alpha\",\"id\":\"100\"}]}";
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
BOOL success = [dictionary objectForKey:@"success"];
if (success) {
    NSMutableArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"domains"];
    NSMutableDictionary *domainsDictionary = [array firstObject];
    NSString *urlString = [domainsDictionary objectForKey:@"URL"];
    NSLog(@"URL: %@", urlString);
}
```